# How to fix: "Could not autowire. No beans of 'JdbcTemplate' type found" in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, jdbc

I followed the examples from SpringBoot Framework which starts here and got the next [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOPX5.png) when I tried to add the Spring bean

Pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.222</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I try to make an insert into bd and bd doesn't change, The app itself works but doesn't connect the database, and JDBC is null.

Comment: IDE not knowing all dependencies and configurations. Ignore it.